# Meaning of "a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, terminology, relations

When we say a function $f$ is defined **on** $\mathbb{R}$, does it mean the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ but not necessarily the co-domain is $\mathbb{R}$, or does it mean both the domain and co-domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm a bit confused because when we are talking about relations, $f$ is a relation **on** $\mathbb{R}$ means that $f\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (and functions are considered to be relations).

Comment: You need more context in order to answer the question.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you mean that the meaning of these sentences vary based on the context?

Comment: I can see where your confusion stems from and this is something that I too questioned as an undergraduate mathematics major. In my experience, when we say "a function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$" we mean the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. However, unfortunately (but just as commonly used) for a general relation $g$ that is not a function when we say "$g$ is a relation on $\mathbb{R}$" we mean $g \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TaylorRendon Thanks for the clarification!